# window.print prints only the first page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, printing

I want to print a report that's more than 1 page long, but when I use 
`window.print()` it only shows the first page! How can I have the other pages?

Note: page variable is longer than 1 page

```js
var page = document.createElement("div");
angular.forEach($scope.customersTasks, function(item) {

  var toPrint = document.getElementById("toPrint");
  page.innerHTML += toPrint.innerHTML;
});

printElement(page);

function printElement(elem) {
  var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
  var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
  if (!$printSection) {
    var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
    $printSection.id = "printSection";
    document.body.appendChild($printSection);
  }
  $printSection.innerHTML = "";
  $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
}
```

```css
@media screen {
  #printSection {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media print {
  body * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printSection,
  #printSection * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #printSection {
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr/demo link? so that we can help better.

Comment: Is the data paged in your UI?

Comment: toPrint is a div in my html page, and i am adding a new one for each task